# How to remove acroread

Tags: dependencies, adobe-acrobat

After trying to install Acroread I did try to  to remove it, with no success,

the message follows. Please help me because the software center was disabled as the result

```
sudo apt-get remove acroread
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'acroread' can't be removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 acroread-bin:i386 : Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.6.27) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable:i386 : Depends: xdg-utils:i386 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installable
 libxml2 : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did u try `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Also see this [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/36315)

Comment: can you post also the output of `dpkg -l | grep acroread` please ?

Comment: And be sure to have read the link provided by blade19899

Comment: Again... try with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Answer (score 0):

1) First, try to correct your apt-get error with this command :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

2) *Optional step* : it might be useful to upgrade your system :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

3) Then remove the package :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge acroread*
```

4) And finally, remove all dependencies that might have to be uninstalled :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I did try all four suggestions with no sucsess, the messages were similar

Comment: I did try all four suggestions with no positive results, the messages were similar to the one included in the onitial question

Comment: can you try `sudo apt-get remove -fm acroread-bin` ?

Comment: I did, get similar messageThe following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable:i386 : Depends: xdg-utils:i386 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installable
 libxml2 : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 is to be installed

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove -fm acroread-bin google-chrome-stable` then.

Comment: I already removed acroread using dpkg

Comment: do the same for google-chrome-stable.